# confusing about storing returned value from function

Tags: c++

I don't sure in which case I should store a returned value of a function by value, reference or const reference.

As I see it, function can return:

(1) by value, if the variable inside is local, and the returned value will be r-value.

(2) by reference, if the variable inside keep existing (for example member field of class), and the
returned value will be l-value ref.

when store it outside:

```
auto& a = getVar(); // should be done **only** if the func returning by ref
auto a = getVar(); // can be done in both cases 
const auto& a = getVar(); // can be done in both cases
```

is it true or am I missing something? is it getting more compilcated when moving? are they cases I didn't think about?

edit:
I understand it is different in case I want a copy to work with or the object itself. but still need some guidelines please to make order in this issue

Comment: What do you plan on DOING with the return value?  That will dictate HOW it should be returned.

Comment: I don't think there is much difference between #1 and #3.

Comment: I think you can only store rvalue in const ref

Comment: @NissimLevy Ah. I see, yeah.

Comment: All three cases are equally valid and commonly used. Which one is the proper choice depends on what you want.